# cmp command return value?

Tags: shell, gnu

I am using the `cmp` command on Ubuntu and I would like some clarification on its return value.

The manual (`$ man cmp`) says nothing about the return value, but suggests looking into the GNU documentation.
So indeed, `$ info cmp` says:

> An exit status of 0 means no differences were found, 1 means some
> differences were found, and 2 means trouble.

(can be found [online here](https://www.gnu.org/software/diffutils/manual/diffutils.html#Invoking-cmp), same sentence).

I understand the 0 and 1 value, but in what situations would `cmp` return the value 2? This is unclear.

Context: I am using that command to check that two files are identical or not, and I would like to know what I am supposed to do if `cmp` returns 2.

Version:

```
$ cmp --version
cmp (GNU diffutils) 3.7
```

Comment: `cmp` source: http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/diffutils.git/tree/src/cmp.c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GNU `cmp` terminates with an exit status of 2 when there is an error preventing it from carrying out the comparison, for example, if one or both of the files can not be found or can't be read:

```bsh
$ cmp asntohe asoneth
cmp: asntohe: No such file or directory
$ echo "$?"
2
```

[The POSIX standard specification for `cmp`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/cmp.html) says that the utility should terminate with an exit status "greater than 1" on "errors".

Comment: Thanks, was suspecting this but manual isn't very clear about this.

Comment: @kebs The POSIX standard just says "on errors", and if you need more specific info about what errors produce an exit status of 2 _specifically_, you will have to look at the documentation and implementation (source code) of the actual utility that you are currently using.

Comment: But it is dependent on the [implementation, shell, and/or operating system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1101957/are-there-any-standard-exit-status-codes-in-linux/1101969#1101969)(?).

Comment: @PeterMortensen The `cmp` utility is not a shell builtin utility, so the utility's exit status is not affected by the shell. The exit status of the utility itself is controlled by the implementation of the utility. The _reported_ exit status may be above 128 if the utility is terminated by a signal (some shells give you 128 + signal number, or 256 + signal number as the status).  In this case, it's not the utility that set the status (as it does not exit, technically, but is killed).

Answer (score 3):

An exit status of 2 means that `cmp` wasn’t able to perform the comparison, for example because it wasn’t able to read one or both of the files. This can happen if one of the filenames points to a directory, or the files don’t exist, or you don’t have permission to read them, etc.

This isn’t exhaustive; `cmp` could also fail if there is insufficient memory for it to perform the comparison.

Answer (score 2):

`cmp` also exits with a status of 2 if you give it in an invalid command line;
e.g., an undefined option (like `-z` or `--foo`) or more than two filenames
(or ***no*** filenames). 
In any case, it should give you an error message describing the problem.

Answer (score 1):

`cmp`s exit status of 2, means "unrecoverable error, I give up". It covers ALL `cmp` exit states other than "same" or "different".

In the Unix tradition of "do one thing well", `cmp` compares two files. It is not a general purpose diagnostic tool.

In the early days of Unix, having the `cmp` binary be small was advantageous. Avoiding "feature creep" contributed to smallness.